# Tableau: Showing Dates not yet in data

Tags: date, tableau-api

In the data underlying my dashboard each row is a type of  encounter, in the table I have rows as facility and columns show number of records by month. The issue I'm having is that the month columns stop where the data stops; for example in one facility the last encounter was in September, when the user looks at it the table stops at September, I need the table to show 0's up to the current month with each month in between (though not in the data) shown. 
If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.kenflerlage.com/2019/03/date-scaffold.html

Comment: Do this in the data layer, not in Tableau.

Comment: Thank you for the informative link.

Comment: If you have a Tableau chart with a *continuous* date axis you can manually edit the limits of the axis to make the end and start any arbitrary value. Right click on the axis and set the axis bounds to be the fixed values you want.